# Apache solr search returning results for log when asked for låg, lög etc. (utf-8 characters)

Tags: apache, solr

I have a site with Drupal, apache solr and tomcat as host for apache solr. I edited the tomcat schema.xml to enable utf-8 support. And that enabled searches for utf-8 characters.

However the actual resultset works unexpectedly. When searching for content with utf-8 characters, apache solr returns content with the "equivalent" character as well.

Example
A search for lag (law) will return content with låg (low). Very different things in Swedish. Is this possible to config. And in that case, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thank you both!

Uncommenting the

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
```

Uncommenting the line above in type="index" och type="query" did the trick.

note `<!--`   below

```
 <analyzer type="query">
    <!--
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory setup in your schema.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case, I will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable by solr. when Solr indexes a record (see type="index"), it uses the analyzers and filters you defined in your schema. Moreover, when you issue a search (see type="query"), the search again will be analyzed by a queryAnalyzer and filters. This is what is defined in the schema. I would suggest using the Solr direct web interface, and anlyze your query as well as your indexing procedure.

for example:

```
 <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="false" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" enablePositionIncrements="true" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" enablePositionIncrements="true" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

for example we can add [solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory)  for replacing accented characters in the ISO Latin 1 character set (ISO-8859-1) by their unaccented equivalent

I would suggest looking at your schema one more time.

Comment: Cheers for that I will look into it.